# R: passing API request as an argument to a function

Tags: r, api, httr

What is the correct way to form an API request which can be passed to a function as an argument?
The request is intended to be constructed inside another function with specific arguments.

An example of the request is the following:

```
library(httr)
GET("http://httpbin.org/get")
```

What I would like to have is **the two functions**:

- one for constructing the request, and
- the other is for sending it.

The idea is to construct the request based on multiple parameters, including POST/GET, headers, tokens, and then to put it to another function, which is responsible for safe sending of the request.

**What I've tried**
A simplified example, which shows the required structure (though it does not work properly).

```
# Function for sending the API request
fn <- function(request) {
  eval(request)
}

# Top function for constructing the request to be sent
fntop <- function(url, type) {
  url <- sprintf("%s%s", url, type)
  my_request <- expression(GET(url))

  fn(my_request)
}
```

The first function works fine when it receives the direct request.

```
fn(GET("http://httpbin.org/get"))
```

However, the same function doesn't work when it is called from the other function with the request containing variables

```
fntop(url = "http://httpbin.org/",
      type = "get")
# Error in as.character(url) : 
#  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

How is it possible to pass API request containing variables as an argument into a function?

Comment: if `type` is parameterized, does that mean you won't always use `GET`?  if so, consider that the `httr::GET` function itself may need to be parameterized, too.

Comment: Can you explain more what exactly you are trying to do? This seems a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It seems odd to store an expression like this. Probably makes more sense to store a list of values that you turn into a function call later. Otherwise it's probably better to at least use `substitute()` or `bquote()` to build the expression for later evaluation.

Comment: @andrew_reece, indeed, I want to place multiple parameters for forming the request. I've just made a very simplified example involving just two parameters.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for your response. I've extended explanation a bit. The top function `fntop( )` is responsible for constructing the request itself based on multiple parameters. It could be GET/POST/PATCH with different content. The other function `fn( )` is intended just to send the final request safely. In my example it contains just one row, but ultimately it may be more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing an expression, just store the data the expression would need. Something like

```
fnmake <- function(verb, url, ...) {
  list(verb=verb, params=list(url, ...))
}
```

and then write a function that can take that data and perform the call

```
fncall <- function(req) {
    call <- if(req$verb=="get") {
      "GET"
    } else if (req$verb=="post") {
      "POST"
    } else stop(paste("Unrecognized verb:", req$verb)
    do.call(call, req$params)
}
```

And if you wanted to combine them into one call,

```
fnall <- function(...) {
   fncall(fnmake(...))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MrFlick. I've actually implemented the same approach to solve my problem. I was wandering if there is a way to put a complete request in the form of expression as an argument to another function?